# How can I store multiple point objects in an array or struct?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to use matlab's drawpoint to capture some points of interest in an image interactively.

The output of the argument is of images.roi.Point object type.

How can I store the selected points in an array or struct, so I can iterate over many points instead of defining a new variable for each point?

This is my code at the moment, it's functional, however I want to be able to loop over a certain number of points instead of defining different variables manually.

```
img = imread('test.jpg');
imshow(img)

p1 = drawpoint;
p2 = drawpoint;
p3 = drawpoint;
p4 = drawpoint;

disp('Press a key when selection is finalized!')
pause;

p = [p1.Position; p2.Position; p3.Position; p4.Position];
```

The reason I'm using drawpoint is that I want to select the points, adjust their position without loosing zooming capability and store all points once finalized.

How can I modify the code to enable iteration over a certain number of points?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know if it is possible to create an array of these objects. I suspect it is possible, but I don’t know exactly what the syntax should look like. You can also use a cell array, as follows:

```matlab
N = 4; % number of points
pts = cell(N,1);
for ii = 1:N
   pts{ii} = drawpoint;
end
pause;
coords = zeros(N,2);
for ii = 1:N
   coords(ii,:) = pts{ii}.Position;
end
```